# How do I redeploy the state server / juju bootstrapped environment

Tags: juju

Basically in my AWS set up I have encountered this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1380337

I am trying to understand how to just reset the state machine to keep all of my environments working re-bootstrap.

Right now my environment is rendered impotent because of this. I don't want to blow everything away just to get back to the same place again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting. It would be useful if you mentioned the version of Juju you are using, and whether you are using the ec2 provider or local on an ec2 machine.

Comment: I blew away the environment because of the agent state, but it was set up using ec2 provider

Answer (score 2):

If you have not already done `juju destroy-environment`, you can do a `juju backups create`, which will create a backup of juju's state in a file called "juju-backup-[yyyymmdd]-[hhmmss].tar.gz" (in side the [] are date and time formats, they and the []s are not literals).

The question is if it will keep your broken state as well, and I can't help you with that - not willing to break what I already have working :)